# Binding an image tag with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I'm trying to update a div with an image and a link when a certain function is called and updates the `images`object.

Here's what I have:

```
<a ng-bind="images[0]" ng-href="{{images[0].link}}"><img ng-bind="images[0]" ng-src="{{images[0].url || '' }}"></a>
```

On the controller:

```
$scope.upload = function (file, pos) {
    $scope.images[parseInt(pos)] = file;
    $scope.images[parseInt(pos)].url = 'http://i.imgur.com/ik9xqXp.jpg?1'
};
```

This function is called when the user submits an image.

However, when the images object updates, instead of an image, I get the string "[object File]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please show the controller where you are updating the images object

Comment: It looks like just a ReferenceError. You want to access certain data but is accessing another instead, as @NagaSandeep said, give us a little bit of code as example.

Comment: Are you sure `images[0].url` returns a string?

Comment: I edited my post with the controller method that updates the images array

Comment: Also, why are you using `ng-bind` - I'm pretty sure `ng-src` does two-way binding already.

Comment: @ForeignObject yup, that was the problem >.< Not it works! If you wish, write this as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `ng-bind` and just use `ng-src`. `ng-src` already handles two-way binding.